# How to solve the inverse square of a matrix without using numpy's solver

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices, A (a 4 x 4 matrix) and b (a 4 x 1) matrix, as shown:

```
A = ([[2, 3, 5, 2],
   [2, 4, 1, 1],
   [1, 7, 4, 2],
   [3, 8, 2, 3]])

b = ([[2], 
      [2],
      [1],
      [5]])
```

I am trying to solve for x in Ax = b. This means that x = A^-1 * b. I tried the built-in matrix solver from numpy but I want to know if there is another way to do so without using this. Perhaps a something with a more lines of code than numpy's solver?

```
 x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

Comment: Fewer than 1 line code is 0, do you want numpy knows what you want and solve it for you, by any chance? :-)

Comment: Sorry I meant few lines of code, meaning I am fine with more lines than the one line of code using numpy's solver

Comment: In that case you have to implement the formula, manually.

Comment: Meaning I use inv(A) * b ?

Comment: Yes, check out the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that but they are only inversing one matrix and not solving for x.